# Asp button doesn't trigger function

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

I have a signup page for my project, and here is the part that doesn't work for me:

```
<input type="email" id="email" title="invalid email!" runat="server" placeholder="email" />
<input type="text" id="username" runat="server" placeholder="username " />
<input type="password" title="Password needs to contain at least one big letter and digits" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$" id="password" runat="server" placeholder="password" />
<input type="text" id="phone" title="invalid phone!" pattern="^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)\s*$" runat="server" placeholder="phone number" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="signUpBotton" OnClick="signUp" Text="sign up"/>
```

I have the sign up part in the code behind, but the `asp:button` doesn't even trigger the function and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your function like a method: "signUp()" not just "signUp"

Comment: This function gets object sender, EventArgs e parametrs

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons, we cannot go ahead and guess all of them that is why you should describe your question as much as you can. So, What I feel here is, that you have a `form` which is being submitted upon clicking that button which is why the original event is being ignored and not triggered. What you may want to do is, set Submit behavior of your button to false. Add this attribute in your button:

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

So, the button markup would like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="signUpBotton" OnClick="signUp" Text="sign up" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```